# Returning a decimal number from a calculation of ranges

Tags: calculus

I'm creating an app and this app has gesture controlled animation. I'm working on a deceleration algorithm, but I'm having a little trouble with a calculation.

I have a timer served by an `interval` (in seconds) and I have a `speed` of gesture swipe. I'm having a little trouble getting the initial time `interval` the first time the timer fires an event.

I somehow need to map `speed` to `interval` to begin deceleration.

At it's fastest, `speed` is `4000` and when `speed` is `4000` I wish to return an `interval` of `0.000001` - the smallest time interval and therefore the timer will fire faster.

At it's slowest, `speed` is `0` and when `speed` is `0` I wish to return an `interval` of `0.01` - the largest time interval and therefore the timer will fire slower.

Thanks for any help you may give me.

Comment: What is the `interval` to be used for? There may be a natural way to map `speed` to `interval`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

if speed $\lt$  0.4 return 0.01

else return 0.004/speed?